# CSS is not applying on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two calendars implemented in one page, but in two different popup boxes. These two calendars have two different CSS applied (e.g. 1.css, 2.css). I used jQuery to enable and disable a calendar in one of the popup boxes. Currently, I am getting new CSS applied when the calendar is open, and removed when the calendar is closed.

My issue is, on first click, it is first applying the old CSS, and after I close the calendar and click it again, then it's applying the new CSS.

Here is the code I used:

```
$('#inputField').datepicker({
 beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('div#div1').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
        $('link[title=2-css]')[0].disabled=false;
    },
 onClose: function() {
        $('div#div2').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
        $('link[title=2-css]')[0].disabled=true;
    }
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with all of your code (including HTML) so we can see the issue live?

Comment: you are appending $('#ui-datepicker-div') to two different locations on the page.  That means the same id will be present in at least 2 locations (possibly more?) on the page.  This can cause bad things to happen.  Normally, jQuery will stop at the FIRST id only.  I'd recommend using a class instead of an id.  But, this may or may not be the actual issue you are seeing here.

Comment: Since, my application has lots of dependencies, I don't think I can replicate the same issue in jsfiddle. But I will try

Comment: @nurdguy: I am using SASS. I have imported all the SASS inside the div1
like: 
#div1{
     import ......;
     import .....
}
Since calendar has same element, appending it inside the empty div allows me to isolate one with another. The above structure is in 2.css. But in 1.css is regular import. Like:

import ......;

I am not using at the rate sign infront of the import because the comment is not allowing me to do so

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. Like I mentioned in my question, I have two calendars on same page with different css. Since, the both calendar has same component, there was namespace conflict. The reason I append datepicker to an empty div was to isolate one calendar with another. Aparently it did work but was not the 100% accurate. So, I changed the namespace of one calendar that is being used as class for css. This solved my problem.